# Multiple Spring Batch Partitioned Jobs Executing Concurrently

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

We have partitioned a large number of our jobs to improve the overall performance of our application. We are now investigating running several of these partitioned jobs in parallel (kicked off by an external scheduler). The jobs are all configured to use the same fixes reply queue. As a test, I generated a batch job that has a parallel flow where partitioned jobs are executed in parallel. On a single server (local testing) it works fine. When I try on a multiple server cluster I see the remote steps complete but the parent step does not ever finish. I see the messages in the reply queue but they are never read.

Is this an expected problem with out approach or can you suggest how we can try to resolve the problem?

Comment: How is your Configuration defined, could you post some more infos?